# Random error noise in Metal fragment shader

Tags: ios, random, fragment-shader, metal, distortion

my circle got distorted, bad.

I'm writing a fragment shader to do some image transformation and I'm seeing some random error noise, not sure what's up.

I'm merging two textures, one read with .read(gid); and one read using a sampler .sample(s, uv);

I created the sampler in Swift and passed it in to the shader.

Here's how I pass in the textures to the shader:

```
texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
texture2d<float, access::read> inTextureA [[ texture(1) ]],
texture2d<float, access::sample> inTextureB [[ texture(2) ]]
```

I get the initial uv coordinates like this:

```
float u = float(gid.x) / float(inTextureB.get_width());
```

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: Random error noise]

Anyone have any clue what's going on?

**Update:**

So I've now switched from a compute shader to a fragment shader with a simple quad to draw on, here's how it's set up:

Swift - Vertecies:

```
let a = Vertex(x: -1.0, y: -1.0, s: 0.0, t: 0.0)
let b = Vertex(x: 1.0, y: -1.0, s: 1.0, t: 0.0)
let c = Vertex(x: -1.0, y: 1.0, s: 0.0, t: 1.0)
let d = Vertex(x: 1.0, y: 1.0, s: 1.0, t: 1.0)
let verticesArray: Array<Vertex> = [a,b,c,b,c,d]
var vertexData = Array<Float>()
for vertex in verticesArray {
    vertexData += vertex.floatBuffer()
}
let dataSize = vertexData.count * MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vertexData[0])
self.vertexBuffer = metalDevice.makeBuffer(bytes: vertexData, length: dataSize, options: [])!
```

Swift - Pipeline:

```
let defaultLibrary = metalDevice.makeDefaultLibrary()!
let vertexProgram = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "basic_vertex")
let fragmentProgram = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "transform")
let pipelineStateDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexProgram
pipelineStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentProgram
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
do {
    self.pipelineState = try metalDevice.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineStateDescriptor)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Swift - Sampler:

```
let samplerDescriptor = MTLSamplerDescriptor()
self.samplerState = metalDevice.makeSamplerState(descriptor: samplerDescriptor)!
```

Swift - Texture:

```
let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(self.pixelBuffer)
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(self.pixelBuffer)
var cvTextureOut: CVMetalTexture?
CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, self.textureCache!, self.pixelBuffer, nil, .bgra8Unorm, width, height, 0, &cvTextureOut)
guard let cvTexture = cvTextureOut, let inputTexture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(cvTexture) else {
    print("Failed to create metal texture")
    return nil
}
```

Swift - Render:

```
let commandBuffer = self.commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
guard let currenDrawable: CAMetalDrawable = self.currentDrawable else { return }

let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = currenDrawable.texture

let renderCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)!

var unifroms: [Float] = ...
let uniformBuffer = self.device?.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * unifroms.count, options: [])
let bufferPointer = uniformBuffer?.contents()
memcpy(bufferPointer, &unifroms, MemoryLayout<Float>.size * unifroms.count)
renderCommandEncoder.setFragmentBuffer(uniformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)

renderCommandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(currenDrawable.texture, index: 0)
renderCommandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(inputTexture, index: 1)

renderCommandEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(self.samplerState, index: 0)


renderCommandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(self.pipelineState)


renderCommandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
renderCommandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 6, instanceCount: 2)


renderCommandEncoder.endEncoding()

commandBuffer.present(currenDrawable)
commandBuffer.commit()
```

Metal - Vertex Shader:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct VertexIn{
    packed_float2 position;
    packed_float2 texCoord;
};

struct VertexOut{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 texCoord;
};

vertex VertexOut basic_vertex(const device VertexIn* vertex_array [[ buffer(0) ]],
                              unsigned int vid [[ vertex_id ]]) {

    VertexIn vertexIn = vertex_array[vid];

    VertexOut vertexOut;
    vertexOut.position = float4(vertexIn.position[0], vertexIn.position[1], 0, 1);
    vertexOut.texCoord = vertexIn.texCoord;

    return vertexOut;
}
```

Metal - Fragment Shader:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct VertexOut{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 texCoord;
};

struct Uniforms{
    float rot;
    float tx;
    float ty;
    float sx;
    float sy;
};

fragment float4 transform(VertexOut out [[stage_in]],
                          texture2d<float>  inTex [[ texture(0) ]],
                          const device Uniforms& in [[ buffer(0) ]],
                          sampler s [[ sampler(0) ]]) {

    float pi = 3.14159265359;

    float u = out.texCoord[0];
    float v = out.texCoord[1];

    float2 size = float2(in.sx, in.sy);

    float ang = atan2(v - 0.5 - in.ty, u - 0.5 - in.tx) + (-in.rot / 360) * pi * 2;
    float amp = sqrt(pow(u - 0.5 - in.tx, 2) + pow(v - 0.5 - in.ty, 2));
    float2 uv = float2(cos(ang) * amp, sin(ang) * amp) / size + 0.5;
    float4 c = inTex.sample(s, uv);

    float r = c.r;
    float g = c.g;
    float b = c.b;

    return float4(r, g, b, 1.0);
}
```

Thats everything!

Even tho I made this huge refactor, all I'm left with is my circle distorted in a new way:

[image: Random error blocks]

Btw I'm running most of this code twice, once for creating the circle (that shader works) and twice for transforming the circle (the shader above).

Anyone see any mistake I'm doing?

I really want my circle to be round.

**Final Update:**

I figured it out!

I was trying to be smart and was looping through the "Swift - Render:" part twice and instead, I'm now looping through everything twice and passing along the currentDrawable texture as a texture input with .setFragmentTexture, it works great now. So pretty much the same code just a different way of executing it.

[image: Round Circle]

My circle is now round.

Comment: What is `gid` in your fragment shader? (For a compute shader, I might assume it's a parameter qualified with the `thread_position_in_grid` attribute, but that doesn't apply to a fragment shader.)

Comment: @KenThomases I got "gid" from a tutorial, it's declared like this: "uint2 gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])", that's how I get the xy coordinates, not sure if there is another way to get uv coordinates?

Comment: Then you're not using a fragment shader, you're using a compute shader. Also, how big is the grid relative to the three textures? Are they all the same size?

Comment: Oh okay, I'm surprised that it works at all, I should prob switch to a fragment shader then. All my textures are 1024x1024.

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code. Show the whole shader function you've been using. Also, show the dispatch call with the values for the threads-per-threadgroup and threadgroups-per-grid.

Comment: @KenThomases I've updated the post with everything I got. I switched to a fragment shader now, tho got a new kinda distorted error noise.

Comment: Solved it! My circle is now round.